# Complex Variables exercise - when does $f'(z) = 0$ implies $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm doing exercise 1.13 from Stein's and Shakarchi's book "Complex Analysis", and it states:

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomophic function. Prove that in any of the cases

a) $Re(f)$ is constant;

b) $Im(f)$ is constant;

c) $|f|$ is constant;

One can conclude that $f$ is constant.

I can see how each of the cases implies that $f'$ is null, however the only thing that I can conlude from that is that $f$ is constant in each connected component of $\Omega$.

Take, for example, $\Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$, where $\Omega_1 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \mbox{ and } Im(z) > 0 \}$ and $\Omega_2 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \mbox{ and } Im(z) < 0 \}$, and define $f$ such that $f(\Omega_1) = \{0\}$ and $f(\Omega_2) = \{i\}$. Clearly, $f$ is holomorphic and $Re(f)$ is constant, so $f$  satisfies a), but is not constant.

Am I missing something? Or is the exercise missing the connectedness hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, $\Omega$ has to be connected. Otherwise the statements are obviously false.

Comment: Without that, you can only conclude that the function is piecewise constant (constant on each connected component). However, look carefully -- they may have hidden connectedness in the terminology; sometimes terms like "domain" are used for $\Omega$ which might mean it is an open connected set.